# Usage of java.util.stream.Collector

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am listing all the available IP of my machine. Its a trivial task but I am trying to use lambda expression. I did it as:

```
ArrayList<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();

StreamUtils.enumerationAsStream(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()).filter(networkInterface -> {
    try {
        return networkInterface.isUp();
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }           

    return false;
}).forEach(networkInterface -> {
    StreamUtils.enumerationAsStream(networkInterface.getInetAddresses()).filter(inetAddress -> {
        return !inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() & inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address;
    }).forEach(inetAddress-> {
        ips.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
    });
});
```

Is there any way to use [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) or any better way?

`StreamUtils#enumerationAsStream` is:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> enumerationAsStream(Enumeration<T> e) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<T>() {
        public T next() {
            return e.nextElement();
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return e.hasMoreElements();
        }
    }, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `&` and `&&`?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [`Stream.flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element

This way, you can turn your stream of NetworkInterfaces into a stream of InetAddresses, which you can then filter, map and collect:

```
networkInterfaceStream.flatMap(networkInterface -> StreamUtils.enumerationAsStream(networkInterface.getInetAddresses()))
        .filter(inetAddress -> { ... })
        .map(inetAddress -> inetAddress.getHostAddress())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with methods that can throw checked exceptions it’s helpful to use utility methods implementing the desired handling, e.g. re-throwing exceptions wrapped in an unchecked exception or, as in your case, implementing rejecting filter behavior:

```
interface ThrowingPredicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t) throws IOException;
}
public static <T> Predicate<T> guard(ThrowingPredicate<T> p) {
    return (x) -> {
        try { return p.test(x); } catch(IOException ex) { return false; }
    };
}
```

with this helper method you can perform your stream operation as follows:

```
List<String> ips =
    StreamUtils.enumerationAsStream(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
      .filter(guard(NetworkInterface::isUp)
         .and(guard(nif-> !nif.isLoopback())))
      .map(NetworkInterface::getInetAddresses)
      .flatMap(StreamUtils::enumerationAsStream)
      .filter(inetAddress -> inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address)
      .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By studying the operations above you might find multiple features or concepts that you might have missed so far and which can help you in the future.